# Force.com CLI - login

Tags: force.com

I am trying to reset password using force.com CLI. Is there a way to run "reset" command only if login command ran successfully? Basically an "if" statement..

```
force login -u=$sfUserName -p=$sfPassword
**IF[SUCCESSFUL]**
THEN
  echo Resetting Salesforce password..
  export sfNewPassword=$(pwgen -cny -B -1 12)
  force password change $sfUserName $sfNewPassword
FI
```

Edit

This is the workaround for now

```
export loginStatus=$(force login -u=$un -p=$pw)
echo
if [[ $loginStatus = *"Logged in as"* ]]
then
   #do your stuff
fi
```

Comment: Any reason you are using the older [Force CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/forcecli) rather than the newer sfdx CLI? Seems like the latter would give you a longer useful lifespan for anything you are creating.

Comment: SFDX also uses OAuth, so it actually gets to use a persistent session that won't expire even when passwords are changed. It's so much more convenient than using the older CLI.

Comment: True. Is the end goal to first validate the existing credentials and then change the password, or just change the password? It looks like SFDX will only generate passwords for scratch orgs out of the box anyway.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox and Daniel Ballinger for prompt response. Long term goal is SFDX but this is something we wanted to get done quickly. I will post the workaround as new comment...

Comment: @SalesforceArchitect I'd suggest posting yoru workaround as a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Daniel Ballinger comment, posting the workaround as solution

```
export loginStatus=$(force login -u=$un -p=$pw)
echo
if [[ $loginStatus = *"Logged in as"* ]]
then
   #do your stuff
fi
```